# Hair Collision with emitter object and other mesh (Blender 3.6)

Tags: hair, collision

I have an urgent issue - to create this hair I added an empty hair curve to the mesh of this figure.

[image: hair curve]

When combing in sculpt mode, I used sculpt collision but the hair still goes through the head in some areas, and also through the mesh of the shirt.

Is there a way to make it collide so it will always stay outside of the mesh?
Or is this even a thing to be solved rather with hair dynamics in the particle system tool? Maybe I missed a crucial step?

[image: view from inside the head to the scalp]

Really stuck here after watching a ton of tutorials already, so I would be very thankful for any tips!
Thank you!